# Error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, debian

I am trying to execute `pg_dump` on PostgreSQL 9.0.4 server running on Debian and I am getting the error below:

```
./pg_dump: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libpq.so.5` is a link to `libpq.so.5.3` as shown below

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Jun 27 16:24 libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 180749 Jun 21 02:43 libpq.so.5.3
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

1: Know the path of `libpq.so.5`

```
find / -name libpq.so.5
```

Output example:
`/usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5`
If found nothing, check if you have already installed the suitable postgresql-libs for your postgresql version and your OS platform

2: Symbolic link that library in a "well known" library path like `/usr/lib`:

```
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
```

Attention:
If your platform is 64 bit, you MUST also symbolic link to 64 bit libraries path:

```
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
```

3: Be happy !

Comment: All postgress utilities were failing with missing libp until I declared LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But then pg_dump failed during import when some other library was loaded. Your hint with ln to well known location solved this issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error after created sym links

Answer (score 17):

## Debian-based Linux distros

Since this is the top search result for the error. I'll add an updated answer. I received the error when trying to start a django server.

I hadn't installed the postgres stuff.

Try:

```bash
sudo apt install libpq-dev

# or
sudo apt install libpq5
```

See:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libpq-dev

### Explanation

Missing the `libpq` dependency is most likely due to installing `psycopg2` via `pip` instead of `apt`. Thus, to avoid any problems with Debian-based distros like Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi OS, do as follows:

```bash
sudo apt install python3-psycopg2
```

Which will nicely pull all the needed dependencies, among which there is `libpq`

Comment: Thanks. This was all I needed.

Comment: great answer. this should be the accepted one

Answer (score 12):

In which directory are these `libpq` files? You can try setting environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to this directory or make sure it's in standard place.

Also, why isn't the `libpq.so.5` link shown in the "as shown below" section? Maybe you should just run `ldconfig`?

Comment: the libpq files are in /opt/postgres/9.0.4/server/lib

Comment: Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/postgres/9.0.4/server/lib ./pg_dump` command.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have even tried EXPORT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/postgres/9.0.4/server/lib before running the command but nothing positive.

Comment: I had to run this `ln -s /opt/postgres/9.0.4/server/lib/libpq.so.5.3 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5` and it worked!

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error message on Postgres 9.5 on RHEL 6.5 which lead me to this post.  But a find for the file `libpq.so.5` returned nothing, which made things more confusing.

In the end the following symbolic links made it run

```
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql95-5  /usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql95-5 
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql95-5  /usr/lib/libpq.so.rh-postgresql95-5
```

These paths are for RHEL, use `find / -name libpq.so` to location your installation and add it to the same destination folders `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/lib64/` using the orginal file name.

The root cause appears that the installation did not place this file into a shared location.

Comment: Only the first ln was needed for me to run it, thanks!

Comment: @smets.kevin Think that will be the case for most people, the second one is added for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

This error probably occurs because of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is not set.

When you install your application from source code using prefix (`./configure --prefix=/some/path`), you have to inform where your `lib/` path is. I just found a [solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679500/4094939), and I added this variable to postgres user init bash script:

```
printf 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apl/pgsql/bin\nexport LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/apl/pgsql/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH\n' > /etc/profile.d/postgres.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

redhat 7 is missing few steps after installing `yum install pgadmin4`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/pgdg-libpq5/lib/libpq.so /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/pgdg-libpq5/lib/libpq.so /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
sudo chown -R apache:apache  /var/lib/pgadmin4/
```

then you can run

```
sudo python3 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
```

and if all successful:

```
systemctl start httpd
systemctl status httpd
apachectl configtest
```

and make sure the httpd starts ok

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with the pg 12 reinstall when recovering from a storage failure. I fixed it by installing the postgressql shared libraries

```
 yum  install postgresql12-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

This must have happened due to mismatched dependencies

I have used

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And after

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

This worked to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem with the pg 9.6 install. I fixed it like this. Rather irritating that the installer doesn't factor this in.

```
***********post yum install & running initdb *********
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/data -l logfile start

-bash-4.2$ /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/data -l logfile start
/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl: **error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

-bash-4.2$ id
uid=26(postgres) gid=26(postgres) groups=26(postgres) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

**************
-bash-4.2$ cat LibFix
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5  /usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5  /usr/lib/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5
**************

[root@****lab ~]# ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5  /usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5
[root@****lab ~]# ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5  /usr/lib/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5

[root@****lab ~]# su - postgres
Last login: Thu Apr  5 08:57:21 CEST 2018 on pts/0

-bash-4.2$ /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/data -l logfile start
server starting

-bash-4.2$ ps -ef | grep postgres
root     12778  7883  0 09:07 pts/0    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres 12779 12778  0 09:07 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
postgres 12802     1  0 09:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/data
postgres 12803 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logger process
postgres 12805 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres 12806 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres 12807 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres 12808 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres 12809 12802  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
postgres 12810 12779  0 09:08 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef

-bash-4.2$ id
uid=26(postgres) gid=26(postgres) groups=26(postgres) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.5)

postgres=# \conninfo

You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```