# psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgresql-11, postgresql-13

Using Fedora33 rn, tried to install Postgresql, was succesful initializing first db, haven't got any errors. Also installed pgadmin4 but couldn't create a server.

```
su -i -u postgres -c "psql"
```

tried this command and got: `

```
psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQgssEncInUse, version RHPG_10
```

tried reinstalling as mentioned and [pg_ctl: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526935/pg-ctl-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpq-so-5/30265074#30265074) but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some PostgreSQL packages installed frombthe Redhat repository and some from the PGDG repository. They don't play together nicely. Don't do that.

Comment: Okay, I got that. Thank you :)