# libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file error on Shopware update

Tags: postgresql, shopware

I am new to Shopware community. I was trying to update Shopware version from 5.4.3 to latest 5.5.4. I was using shell commands for the purpose. For that, first I tried to update the Shopware from 5.4.3 to 5.4.6. But when I run php recovery/update/index.php I got the following error on terminal.

> php: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I search over internet, I got [Error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781566/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpq-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file). It says I need to install postgresql-libs in system. As of I know Shopware not using postgresql.

What may be the reason I am getting this error. Is that because of some other process  running behind??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was the issue with the shared hosting. I removed update-assets folder and again tried from the shopware backend, and it updated properly.